# Fullscreen iPhone animation from PNG

Tags: iphone, png, uiimageview, uiimage, frame-rate

I need in animation of sequence of more PNG files (300 png files and size is 320x480).
I've try make it with **12 fps**, but sometime iPhone 3g have lags... 3gs working fine. I think 2g working with lags always.

I've use one UIImageView and loading images in NStimer callback by UIImage:imageWithContentOfFile.

May be this is not best way to animation png files ?

note: previously i've used **ImageOptim** to pack (or strip ??) all my images (from 20% to 80% of size strip).

regards,

Answer (score 2):

Using an image view for full-screen animation is really not going to go well, regardless of how you compress your images. Make the frames into a video file and use `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I found is use JPG files it works really faster.
And we do not need PNG if fullscreen animation (tested on iPhone and iPad).

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford some sort of delay when the apps start, you may cache some images (say, storing them in `NSMutableArray`) before displaying them. This assume the bottleneck is in the `imageWithContentOfFile` call.

One more option is to keep imaging loading in a `NSOperation` (thread in its simpler form).

Comment: Yes, i think bottleneck is imageWithContentOfFile.

THank you very much i will try both methods.